# Push all git commits as one to empty bare repo

Tags: git, git-bare

I have two bare repositories.

`repo1` - with all the history
`repo2` - new, empty one

I want to push all the files from `repo1` to `repo2`, but without the whole history, just the the state from the last commit.

I don't want to touch the history of the `repo1` (it's best to assume it's read only). In the new repo I don't want to have any history (including reflogs), so shashing after the push is not an option.

Is this ever possible without creating new, temporary repository?
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
git checkout --orphan temp_branch
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push repo2 temp_branch:master
```

This will create a temp_branch locally with just a single commit with the current snapshot, and push it to a branch called "master" on repo2.

Comment: checkout in bare repository results in: `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: @hagello Both of the repos are bare, without work tree.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming you were in a non-bare repo. Go ahead and clone repo1 into a non-bare repo; you can pass `--depth 1` to `git clone` (to speed things up) since you are only going to be making an orphan branch anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to do it without creating the new repo :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to clone the head of `master`and assuming that you do not insist on a `git push`:

```
# in repo2
# git fetch --depth 1 path_to_repo1 master:master
```